# How to iterate through instances of a class in VB.NET for UWP

Tags: vb.net, class, for-loop, iteration, uwp

Again MSDN doesn't help. UWP seem to be very immature.
Coming to my question: how can I iterate through instances of a class in a UWP app?
The usual 'for each' seems not to be the best approach.
I scrolled the already posted questions, but none involves VB.NET for UWP
(C# accepted though)

Comment: Please add a code sample of what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

UWP is a platform with contracts and design commonality, i don't see how that would affect the language itself such as VB or C#. You should be able to loop through a collection normally. I don't see why for each would not be a good approach.

Comment: There is no collection of controls, for example.

Comment: Yes but this is due to XAML for UI. XAML is xml based so you don't really need classic collections, that would be handled differently using ItemsControl class and templating. ItemsControl would be the closest thing to classic collections.

Comment: Ok, I would iterate through collection of instances of a class via for example a List(of something). Thanks.